# Каракули вместо русских букв

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД в кодировке utf8_ general_ci.
Есть запрос на вывод данных из таблицы. Если нужен, вот он ниже:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT `shoutbox`.id AS id,`shoutbox`.date AS date,`shoutbox`.user AS user,`shoutbox`.message AS message FROM `shoutbox` ORDER BY `shoutbox`.id DESC;";
$mysql_result = mysql_query ($query);
?>

<table id="reviews_table" border="0"> 
<?php
    $class_num = 2;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($mysql_result)) {
        $class_num = 3 - $class_num;?>
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td width="90px">
        <span class="date"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["user"]); ?></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <font class="faq_text"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["message"]); ?>    </font>
    </td>

</tr>

<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Вместо русских букв выводится ???�?�???? ?�?�?�?�

Как исправить, куда копать?

Пробовал писать

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8"); iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "Windows-1251"); ob_start("ob_iconv_handler");
```

Не помогло

Comment: Если бы мне за каждый ответ на эту тему платили по одному центу, то я бы уже был миллионером )) 

Заголовки - это хорошо, iconv - плохо, но проверьте, чтоб документы были сохранены в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM, убедитесь, что сравнение для текстовых полей формы установлено сравнение utf8_general_ci, после подключения к БД сделать запрос:

    SET NAMES utf8

В htaccess прописать строку:

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: Некоторые таблицы в 1251, мне нужно вывести на одной только странице в утф-8. Поэтому htaccess менять не вариант
 
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
 
Прописал это, каракули стали загагулинами типа Ð¾Ñ‚Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ð¾! Ð

Comment: @Rammsteinik, теперь попробуйте снять iconv

Comment: Не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала используйте комментарий [@Rammsteinik](/users/11413/rammsteinik)

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

А потом ответ [@lopar](/users/6919/lopar)

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Все это должно выдать Вам нужный результат)

И еще на всякий случай где нибудь в php:
    setlocale (LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте чтобы на этой странице были в наличии:

1. `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`
2. Сама страница сохранена в кодировке UTF-8. *Текстовый файл* с кодом.